# CQWP resets to default

Tags: web-part, 2013, content-query-web-part

I am having problem using CQWP on one of my page. You know under "Query" in CQWP you get 3 options:

- Show items from all sites in this site collection
- Show items from the following site and all subsites
- Show items from the following list

The first option is the default one. Now what happens is, when I select option 3, the page reloads and CQWP resets to default i.e. option 1 is selected. No matter how much I select option 3, the page refreshes and then resets to option 1.
This page has no other web part except this one. I have deleted and added CQWP but no luck.  I have also deleted the web part zone and added again but same problem.

I remember a couple of days ago I was having exact same problem on home page but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have custom JavaScript in you masterpage which might conflict with the web part?

Comment: But same web part is working fine on another page. And my javascript is included in master page which means it is part of every page that I add.

Comment: I have removed all jquery and other scripts including CSS but same problem. Also reset IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Since this was a target page on variation site, I went to parent site, Site Settings, Variation Settings and then I selected "Update Web Part changes to target pages when variation source page update is propagated.

After that I went to my source page and published it again and propagated changes and after 5 minutes when the timer job ran, I can see the web part on my target page with correct settings.